# How to find the range of $f(x) = {e^x \over x-1}$

Tags: functions

I want to find the range of the following function :

$$f(x)  = {e^x \over x-1}$$

How do I find the range of the above function ? I have tried a lot , but do not have any idea to solve this.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: try finding its limits at $\infty$, $-\infty$, $1^{+}$, $1^{-}$ and then look for local extrema elsewhere

Comment: What did you try?  Please provide details.

Comment: It would perhaps help to edit the definition of *range of a function* into the question, applied to your particular case. Then please also edit in what you think happens to $f(x)$ as $x \to \{\pm \infty, 1^+, 1^-\}$ and try to draw conclusions. You will get further hints then.

Comment: I have tried to find the inverse of f(x) = (e^x)/(x-1) . But I am not be successful in this work.

Comment: I have understood the above answer . When x->1 then f(x) -> 0 So the range is R-{0}

Comment: You're right that $\{0\}$ is not in the range. But it would really help you to [graph $f(x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+e^x%2F%28x+-+1%29) to notice an interval that needs exclusion from the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discontinuity at $x=1$. Analyze both sides separately. Let's call $f_1$ the function over the subset of the domain $(1,\infty)$, and $f_2$ the function over the subset of the domain $(-\infty,1)$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x}{x+1}=\frac{e^x(x-2)}{(x-1)^2}$$

There is a local minimum at $x=2$:

$$f_1(2)=e^2$$

$$\lim_{x\to{\infty}}f_1(x)=\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to{1}^+}f_1(x)=\infty$$

The range of $f_1(x)$ is therefore $[e^2,\infty)$.

Do the same for f_2(x):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f_2(x)=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to{1}^-}f_2(x)=-\infty$$

The range of $f_2(x)$ is therefore $(-\infty,0)$

The range of the full function is the union of these two intervals.

Comment: I will not be able to discover this answer . For this math , I have spent 3 hours . At last , I have got the solution . Thanks .

Comment: @OchenaPothik You're quite welcome. Is it clear? Is there anything you still don't understand?

Comment: I have understood the above procedure .

Comment: And I have to apply same procedure to find the range of (ln x) / (x-1) . Isn't it ?

Comment: @OchenaPothik More or less. The only difference is the domain of this function is $(0,\infty)\setminus1$, but it still has the same asymptote. So it's the same procedure, but keep in mind the different domain.

Answer (score 4):

** Hint**

What happend when $x$ is very close to $1$ from above? from below?

Comment: This hint is not useful for me . Plz write in a details

Comment: @OchenaPothik It's not useful because you haven't stated what you've tried or where you're having trouble.

Comment: I have understood the above answer . When x->1 then f(x) -> 0 So the range is R-{0}

Comment: @OchenaPothik No, it doesn't approach $0$ as $x\to1$. You need to re-think your math here.